# using python with Django frame work

Tags: django

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    Employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    Branch= models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    EmpAddress = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    JoiningMonth=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    Department = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

How can i customize or resizing the text field in last one

Answer (score 0):

Not in the model.

[`Charfield`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#charfield)

[Widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#module-django.forms.widgets)

Comment: sorry how customize for text field